# Can I Clear App Storage with React Native?

Tags: react-native

Can I clean App cache and storage with a function in React Native?

I have a project with some internal databases and I need to clear all data in one process, however some databases doesn't have a function to clear database.

Comment: Well if you're talking about just some files in the application storage directory (e.g. SQLite) you can simply delete the files?

Comment: These files are not one sqlite. An example is Watermelon DB, that create a lot files so save some data.